# Using COUNT and DISTINCT in the same SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server table **Cascading** with following structure:

```
+----+--------+----------------+           +----------------+-----------+  
| ID | NodeID | ActivationTime |           | ActivationTime | NodeCount |  
+----+--------+----------------+           +----------------+-----------+  
| 1  | 448    | 1              |           | 1              | 1         |  
| 2  | 195    | 2              |           | 2              | 3         |  
| 3  | 504    | 2              |           | 3              | 6         |  
| 4  | 609    | 2              |           | ...            | ...       |  
| 5  | 15     | 3              |           | ...            | ...       |  
| 6  | 31     | 3              |    =>     | ...            | ...       |  
| 7  | 56     | 3              |           | ...            | ...       |  
| 8  | 461    | 3              |           | ...            | ...       |  
| 9  | 585    | 3              |           | ...            | ...       |  
| 10 | 345    | 3              |           | ...            | ...       |  
| .. | ...    | ...            |           | ...            | ...       |  
+----+--------+----------------+           +----------------+-----------+
```

I need to calculate the number of times NodeID is appearing in the table with DISTINCT ActivationTime. For instance, 1 node at ActivationTime 1, 3 nodes at ActivationTime 2, 6 nodes at ActivationTime 3 and so on. The desired result is shown at the right side.

I tried the following unsuccessful query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ActivationTime) FROM CASCADING WHERE ActivationTIme IN
(SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(ActivationTime)) AS NodeCount FROM CASCADING
GROUP BY ActivationTime)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNT(DISTINCT NodeID) and GROUP BY ActivationTime

```
SELECT ActivationTime, COUNT(DISTINCT NodeID) NumberOfID
FROM
  CASCADING
GROUP BY ActivationTime
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT NodeID)`

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(NodeCount) AS Count, ActivationTime FROM CASCADING
GROUP BY ActivationTime

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by following:

```
select activationtime, count(*) from cascading group by activationtime;
```